# Is there a way to detect squares drawn by characters in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a project in Python where you have a 5x4 two-dimensional list with empty strings as elements. These "slots" are later filled in with either "A" or "B", depending on the user input. After all the elements are changed with A's or B's, I want to find out how many 2x2 squares that are made up only by A's and B's (if they form at all) after there are 20 inputs.
[If a formation like this occurs, it should count as two squares.]

[image: 2]

I can't wrap my head around this. So any help would be appreciated.

(I can't use any kind of third party libraries. But any built-in Python library would be OK.)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Maybe start by writing some code to detect repeating characters in each row then see how you can extend it to see if they are part of a square?

Comment: Well, there are 20 1x1 squares, right?  That's not the question.  You have highlighted a rectangle.  Do you want squares or rectangles?  You just do it by hand, element by element.  Search for 4x4 squares (there are only two possibilities), then search for 3x3 squares, then 2x2.

Comment: Hi, i want to have squares that consists of 4 A's or 4 B's.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions .. if you had just four values in a grid of some kind, could you tell if they were all the same?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So you want 2x2 squares -- if so you should edit your question so that is isn't asking about1x1 squares. As a hint -- one strategy is to focus on determining if a cell is the upper left corner of a 2x2 square.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new at this site and I don't know much about anything. Thank you for your answers and advices. I've edited my question and I will continue to edit it based on what you have wrote.

Comment: Please show your efforts. Detecting such a square means you need to compare values. Please show your attempted code, and where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2x2 square contains just a single value. Thus, if you form the set of those 4 elements, that set would have length 1. This is easy enough to implement:

```
def count_squares(mat):
    m = len(mat) #number of rows
    n = len(mat[0]) #number of columns
    count = 0
    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(n-1):
            if len(set([mat[i][j],mat[i][j+1],mat[i+1][j],mat[i+1][j+1]])) == 1:
                count += 1
    return count

mat = [['A','A','A','B','B'],
       ['A','A','B','A','A'],
       ['A','A','B','B','A'],
       ['B','A','A','B','A']]

print(count_squares(mat)) #prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
import numpy

def main(l1, l2, A, B, input_list):
    check = numpy.ones((l1, l2)) * A
    pos = []
    for j1 in range(len(input_list) - l1 + 1):
        for j2 in range(len(input_list[0]) - l2 + 1):
            if input_list[j1:j1+l1, j2:j2+l2].all() == check.all():
                pos.append([j1, j2])
    return pos

if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = 1  # Value of A
    B = 0  # Value of B
    l1 = 2  # Horizontal size of A values searched
    l2 = 2  # Vertical size of A values searched
    input_list = numpy.array([  # User input
        [A, A, A, B, B],
        [A, A, B, A, B],
        [A, A, B, B, A],
        [B, A, A, B, A],
    ])
    
    pos = main(l1, l2, A, B, input_list)
    
    print(f"{input_list = }")
    print(f"{pos = }")
```

Result:

```
input_list = array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
pos = [[0, 0], [1, 0]]
```

The output return the top left corner of square of 2x2 containing only 1 values. Here you just need the len of 'pos' to count how many square you have...